# R saves plot in png but not in pdf

Tags: r, pdf, acrobat

I'm trying to save a toy plot in a file. It works for png, but not for pdf. The pdf is simply empty.

```
width =  1144
height = 995

png("deleteme.png", width = width, height = height)
op=par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
plot(c(0, width), c(0, height), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "",xaxs = "i",yaxs = "i")
lines(c(1,2,3,4)*100, c(3,2,3,5)*100)
dev.off()

pdf("deleteme.pdf", width = width, height = height)
op=par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
plot(c(0, width), c(0, height), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "",xaxs = "i",yaxs = "i")
lines(c(1,2,3,4)*100, c(3,2,3,5)*100)
dev.off()
```

This is the png: [image]

and here is the pdf: http://docdro.id/wG9xx3J

The pdf shows the lines in chrome, but not in Acrobat!

Comment: Seems 1144 x 995 is out of range, since pdf proportions are calculated in inches. Try `width=8, height=6`.